# My input pattern doesn't work

Tags: html, regex

I've created a regex for checking a date format ( 01-01-0000 to 31-12-9999).
I tried an example regex, and it works, so there is something wrong with my regex, but when I try it in a debugger (regexr) it works just fine.

What am I missing?

```
([0]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1-2]{1}[0-9]{1}|[3]{1}[0-1]{1})(\-)([0]{1}[1-9]{1}|[1]{1}[0-2]{1})(\-)\d{4}
```

New regex after edit:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}
```

I use an html input type text, and put the regex in pattern ="my pattern".

Thanks in advance (:

Edit: Fixed the regex according to Casimir et Hippolyte's comment, and now it works.

Comment: Is there some error you are getting? What Output do you expect? What language (`JavaScript`)?

Comment: did you put the `/g` flag at the end?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz The example I tried that worked didn't have that either, and mine doesn't work either when I do use it

Comment: The `{1}` quantifiers are useless as a character class around a single character, remove that. There's no character between 0 and 1 building the range `0-1` doesn't make sense. Also `-` isn't a special character, you don't have to escape it. Stop to put parenthesis everywhere when you have nothing to group.

Comment: @Jan It's an input field in html, I use pattern ="the pattern". Will update question.

Comment: Can you post the code where you test your regex? maybe your are missing something and the regex is all fine

Comment: your regex can't check if the months have 30 or 31 days or for february (28-29)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks, I fixed everything you said and now it works!

Comment: It seems after some tests that the problem was the wrong character ranges.

Comment: After removing all that is useless the pattern can be shorten to: `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex looks OK, at least it captures your both sample dates (tested on regex101.com).

You can simplify it a little:

- No need for `[...]` around a single char (e.g. change `[0]` to `0`).
- No need for capturing groups around a dash (e.g. change `(-)` to `-`).
- It is strange that you used capturing groups for day and month, but you
  didn't for year field (I added it in the example below).

So try the following regex:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(\d{4})
```

It is however not clear, whether you realy need capturing groups.